# Facebook sharing not working normally

Tags: facebook, sharing

After facebook sharing I need return to my website. But facebook redirect me to [https://www.facebook.com/dialog/return/close#*=*](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/return/close#_=_). Earlier all work good. Can you help me with this problem?

Code:

facebook script:

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

share link:

```
<a href='https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A//www.mysite.com/share/somepost/1>Share on Facebook</a>
```

Comment: Yes enter your website in the browser and press go.. or maybe explain what you're actually doing programmatically!?

Comment: I added code in main question

Comment: you do not need to include the js sdk when using sharer.php...make sure you know what each code you use does. don´t just copy and paste.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it. But problem still exist.

Comment: Implement the URL redirect version of the current Share dialog, and specify the redirect_uri. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#redirect